# Number of points on elliptic curve

Tags: cryptography, elliptic-curve

If you have an elliptic curve in the form of:

```
y^2 = x^3 + a*x + b  (mod p)
```

Is there a good program to calculate the number of points on this curve?

I have read about Schoof's and Schoof-Elkies-Atkin (SEA) algorithm, but I'm looking for open source implementations. Does anyone know a good program that can do this?

Also if a is 1 and b is 0, the SEA algorithm can't be used because the j-invariant is 0. Is this correct?

Comment: I think you need to be more specific. What's the available point-space? Integers? Reals? There are infinite points unless you constrain the problem otherwise.

Comment: The OP said "mod p" which implies integers.

Comment: Context is probably elliptic-curve cryptography but I'm not sure, the math is a bit over my head.

Comment: It is an interesting subject and I have found some theory on elliptic curves modulo p in one of my old math book. If you are interested I can present some information (but no solution). And I'm not sure if I still understand the complete math, but it is interesting stuff.

Comment: I'm talking about this book: "http://www.amazon.com/Factorization-Primality-Testing-Undergraduate-Mathematics/dp/0387970401"

Comment: Is a better question to ask what metrics to use to calculate number of points on a curve?

Comment: The question is phrased absolutely correctly for anyone involved in the field. What is meant by number of points of an elliptic curve E mod p is the number of points in the affine plane over the field with p elements A^2(F_p) (or the number of points in the projective plane P^2(F_p)).

Comment: Future questions of this type should probably be posted on the [Cryptography Stack Exchange](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some links here:
[Implementations of portions of the P1363 draft](http://grouper.ieee.org/groups/1363/P1363/implementations.html) (wayback [backup link](https://web.archive.org/web/20170114091037/http://grouper.ieee.org/groups/1363/P1363/implementations.html) of this page).

Comment: "A C++ Implementation Implementation of the Schoof's Algorithms for Counting Points on an Arbitrary Elliptic Curve by Mike Scott" did the job. I had to make a few changes so it worked for large numbers. That is: increase the size of arrays and the precision of "Big" numbers.

Comment: Links are dead for me on that page, can anyone mirror?

Comment: @samoz Just modified answer a bit to include Wayback [backup link](https://web.archive.org/web/20170114091037/http://grouper.ieee.org/groups/1363/P1363/implementations.html), I hope original author of an Answer doesn't mind, because starting from 2014 he didn't reply yet to your request of updating dead link.

Answer (score 3):

Have you heard of [Sage](http://sagemath.org/)?

Sage includes Pari, which is an open source package for number theory. Pari has an implementation of SEA.

From http://wstein.org/papers/2008-bordeaux/sphinx/elliptic_curves.html#schoof-elkies-atkin-point-counting:

```
sage: k = GF(next_prime(10^20))
sage: E = EllipticCurve(k.random_element())
sage: E.cardinality()                   # less than a second
100000000005466254167
```

Answer (score 2):

I have been using Mike Scotts program(miracl) for this purpose also.
Being just curious may I ask: How large were the domains with prime group order you could produce with the software?
I got up to 1024 bit and now quit because I need my office PC for something other than running  point counting software for weeks on end. 
Did you produce larger domains? If so I would be glad to get the domain parameters and if you don't have objections would include them in my ECC-Software Academic Signature.

My domains can be found here [ECC Domain Page](http://www.fh-wedel.de/~an/crypto/accessories/domains_anders.html).
The software to use them with is accessible from here [Manual with Link to download page](http://www.fh-wedel.de/~an/crypto/Academic_signature_eng.html)

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried Sage. It took me around 3-4 hours to compile to x64 ubuntu. It seems to be a good program. But when the j-invariant is 0 the SEA algorithm can't be used, and then it seems to have some problems if you use large values for p/k.

After searching some more I also found miracl: http://www.shamus.ie/index.php?page=elliptic-curves
They have implementations for both the normal Schoof and SEA algorithm. But this program also has some problems when using large input values. After 3-4 hours of running it crashed :/. I tried to fix it, and currently it's running again so hopefully it will work.

Edit: It works now. The program in the link above is identical to the one Rasmus Faber gave.