# Elliptic curve and point cardinalities

Tags: python, cryptography, elliptic-curve

currently working on generation elliptic curve for ECDSA and met some problems:
An elliptic curve: `y**2 = x**3 + ax + b (mod p)`
Point on elliptic curve: `G = (Gx, Gy)`

1. How to find a **cardinality of Elliptic curve**?
2. How to find the **order of point G** on that elliptic curve?

---

-- As for `1.`: the cardinality may be found with [SEA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schoof%E2%80%93Elkies%E2%80%93Atkin_algorithm) (which fit nicely for large modules `p`). Is there any implementation for [SEA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schoof%E2%80%93Elkies%E2%80%93Atkin_algorithm) within Python?
-- As for `2`: any solution within Python?

**P.S.**
Sorry for my English and thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is related to this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/408645/624829).

[Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/) is a powerful math package with a Python front-end. With Sage you will be able to use [PARI/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/doc.html) package

You have also some information in their [FAQ](http://www.math.u-bordeaux.fr/~belabas/pari/doc/faq.html#ell) about elliptic curves

Comment: can it be used like `import sage` `EC.cardinality()` in python?

Comment: You will be able to do so as per this [example](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/faq/faq-usage.html#how-do-i-import-sage-into-a-python-script) and [ec doc](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/sage/schemes/elliptic_curves/ell_finite_field.html). Yet you need to run your script through the sage special version of Python interpreter as mentioned in the FAQ